# How can I check if an object has been created/called upon in Java? (Eclipse IDE)

Tags: java, eclipse, object

Suppose I was making a game and within the render method which cycles hundreds of times per second I have two lines of code e.g.

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite (...);
screen.renderSprite(...);
```

Which creates an object and renders it onto the screen so it shows. But suppose it didn't show; it would be natural to assume that if there is no error then *it just wasn't called*.

So in Eclipse how I can check if these two lines of code have been called in line x? If you tell me to use breakpoints tell me step by step because I feel that would only obfuscate the render method. (?) I want to check if the object has been created and utilized.

---

If you need more information don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I would use a LOGGER for this case

Comment: The modulus operator can be helpful to reduce the flood of information in logs or debug-prints. In a field, count the number of times the code has been called. Then, log the count only when (0 == (count % n)), e.g., where n is a 100, or a 1000 ...

Comment: Would using Mockito be helpful?

Comment: Seems to me like you want your game to be able to report if an entity of type 'X/Y' (say: sprite/player) has been rendered at a certain point in time. Which would mean that you make your game keep that kind of runtime information available for you in some way or another.

Answer (score 0):

```
11. Sprite sprite = new Sprite (...);
12. screen.renderSprite(...);
```

1. Right click on line **12** (in my example but will be different in your code.)
2. Click on **Toggle breakpoint**
3. Click *Run > Debug As* an then either selct Java Application or an existing launch configuration

Once the code starts and enters `screen.renderSprite`, the program will halt and you'll be able to check it.

Comment: The OP knows about breakpoints. The question asks what to do in the face of calls "hundreds of times per second."

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will have to identify some lines in your code at which you know that your sprite wasn't rendered (maybe a state flag?).

From that you have two options:

1. If you maintain the source code of method **#renderSprite(...)** you should consider using a logger (like [apache logging](http://logging.apache.org/) which should be already included as a plugin of your Eclipse IDE). Thus your application wouldn't obfuscate your rendering processes.
2. The other option would be debugging: Set up a breakpoint (double-click left of said lines) and run your application in debug mode. You can also set conditions for the breakpoint to stop only in certain cases. Therefor you'll have to right-click a breakpoint and choose "*Breakpoint Properties...*" and check the "*conditional*"-box. In the textfield below you can define your condition in Java (you'll have access to all variables just like in your Editor). For more information see the [debug help page of Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/cdebugger.htm) or [Lars Vogel's tutorial on debugging](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html). By debugging your rendering would be paused, but it should be easier for you to find the concrete source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A line with a breakpoint set, whose bytecode has been executed, will have a little checkmark on the breakpoint image.